# What is Market application's APK named?

Tags: android, google-play

I was trying to flash an update ROM.

I want to remove the stock Browser and Market applications

I removed the `Browser.apk` and `MarketUpdater.apk` from the system/app folder of the update archive

After flashing, when I checked `Settings > Applications`, there is no Browser app which is expected, but Market application is there and it is working fine. Which means I should remove some thing other than `MarketUpdater.apk`. What is Market application's APK named?

Comment: Isn't this better suited for http://android.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#questions says `'Developing/programming for Android` are off-topic there and to ask these questions on Stack Overflow

Comment: This isn't a development or programming question. It's related to customizing your android device, unless I'm misunderstanding

Comment: I think create/flash a custom ROM comes under the scope of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search vending_xxxx.apk is exist in it or not